# How to display particular set of wordpress post on a webpage?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a **wordpress/php** code as shown below which display list of posts on a webpage.

> 1st Php code:

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'cpac-special-report',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2 ? 3 : 4
]);
```

On debug `<?php echo json_encode($special_reports); ?>` it displays the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "post_type": "cpac-special-report",
        "orderby": "menu_order",
        "order": "ASC",
        "fields": "ids"
    },
    "posts": [149443, 149551, 149488],   /* Posts id here is displaying on the basis of weight order ASC */
    "max_num_pages": 54
}
```

What I want now in the **following php**, I want **post id 149443(meaning 1st post) to show up at Line A** and **post ids 149551(2nd post) and 149488(3rd post) at Line B**.

> 2nd php code:

```
<?php if ($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2) { ?>

<?php if ($special_reports->have_posts()) : while ($special_reports->have_posts()) : $special_reports->the_post(); ?>
          // Here I want to display post id 149443 (lets call as tile A)                      /* Line A */     
<?php endwhile; endif;

<div class ="test">
    <p>Some Content</p> // Here I am displaying tile B          
</div>

<?php if ($special_reports->have_posts()) : while ($special_reports->have_posts()) : $special_reports->the_post(); ?>
         // Here I want to display post ids 149551 and  149488  (lets call as tiles C and D) /* Line B */    
<?php endwhile; endif;

<?php                   
}                   
?>
```

The graphical representation of the above php code should be:

```
Tile A   Tile B       Tile C   Tile D
149443   Some Content 149551   149488
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in both the php code above so that **1st post id 149443 displays at Line A** and **2nd/3rd post ids (149551 and 149488)   display at Line B**.

Comment: In that case, don't put it in a while loop. If has post then use the post. Or use a counter, to insert "Some Content" in between. If counter == 1; print content.

Comment: @lbu I am wondering if you can explain me in an answer. It would give me much better idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please add the following code


$special_reports_posts = $special_reports->posts();

$counter = 1;
foreach( $special_reports_posts as $special_reports_post ){

   if( $counter == 1 ){

      echo $special_reports_post->post_title; // (lets call as tile A)

      ?>
      <div class ="test">
        <p>Some Content</p> <!-- Here I am displaying tile B -->         
      </div>
      <?php

   }


   if($counter >1){
      echo $special_reports_post->post_title; // (lets call as tiles C and D)
   }


   $counter++;
   }
```

Comment: You could use `else` instead of `if($counter >1)`.